# Inspect element from my WPF WebBrowser, using "inspect element(s)"(IE,Chrome,Firefox) to get the css path("copy css-path")

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

I need the correct css path from a webpage, which will be displayed in my WPF application(to use it later with HTMLAgilityPack and/or Fizzler).

Something like [this](http://blog.utest.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/06/Firebug-3.png), to "copy css-path" or xpath(FireBug), should be the final goal.

I also found some interesting post like:

- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207003/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-how-to-get-data-under-mouse-pointer)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396121/how-can-i-get-text-under-mouse-pointer-webbrowser-control)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219526/html-render-with-inspect-element-functionality-how-to-c-sharp)
- [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32279/How-To-Tell-What-is-Clicked-in-a-WebBrowser-Contro)

They all use "webBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint", "webBrowser.GetElementFromPoint"  or "PointToClient", but I can not find it in any library and not even on [msdn.microsoft(WebBrowser Class)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

By the way I use the "WebBrowserControl" from visual studio 2010 toolbox to display my webpage.

Then I found some function on the client-side, but this can not be the thing they meant([javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint))...

**updated:12 th june, 08:15 pm**

This is actually a nice [post by "dick"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527036/how-to-read-element-content-from-web-page-using-the-wpf-webbrowser-component):

```
    private void myBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic doc = myBrowser.Document;
    dynamic htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
    string htmlstring = htmlText;
}
```

This works, but this stands in no relation to my WPF element.
I get only the html but not the corresponding element.
I could search for the text in that html doc, but if it appears more than once, its is not unique anymore.

**updated: 13 th june, 07:15 a.m**

Based on [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/) tutorial I found a workaround.

I included this namespace in my ".xaml":

```
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
```

Then I added the the old winforms browser:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfhSample" Margin="372,12,12,205" MouseLeftButtonDown="wfhSample_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        <wf:WebBrowser />
    </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Added to my "MainWindow()" a starting value:

```
MainWindow(){
 (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Navigate("http://www.google.de/");
 }
```

The actual part, to get the element:

```
 /*
    System.Drawing.Point point = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
    ...myMethod(..., (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser), point.X, point.Y);
    */
     ...myMethod(...,System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser refWebBrowser2,Int32 valScreenX, Int32 valScreenY,....){

    Point refPoint = refWebBrowser2.PointToClient(new Point(valScreenX, valScreenY));

    System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement refHtmlElement = refWebBrowser2.Document.GetElementFromPoint(refPoint); //System.Drawing()

    return refHtmlElement.TagName;
    }
```

The only problem,which is left by now is that the event handler does not fire(I added them over the properties window):

```
//winforms-browser
                    private void wfhSample_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("old");

        }

        //wpf-browser
                private void browser_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("new");

        }
```

Why can't I overwrite the event handler(not even the right button) ?

**updated: 13 th june, 07:45 a.m**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189510/wpf-webbrowser-mouse-events-not-working-as-expected) could be an useful article, I will check this out.

**updated: 16 th june, 07:00 a.m**

Now I found a solution, where I can handle an event for a wpf-webbrowser, but not for the old winforms-browser.

```
    //new WPF webbrowser  
      private void browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
            {
                mshtml.HTMLDocument doc;
                doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
                mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent;
                iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)doc;
                iEvent.onclick += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(NewClickEventHandler);
            }

             private bool NewClickEventHandler(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
            {
            //the click event handler works, but I have no access to "GetElementFromPoint"
 // it does not exist
                        //Point refPoint = browser.PointToClient(new Point(valScreenX, valScreenY));
                //System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement refHtmlElement = browser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(refPoint);
                //return refHtmlElement.TagName;
                //because the new wpf control does not support for example 'GetElementFromPoint()'
            // I need to get the html controls conntected to the wpf cursor
            }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373853/net-webbrowser-control-get-active-contextmenu) helped me and I changed the event handling for Winforms webbrowser in my wpf application to:

```
//old Winforms webbrowser
        private void wfhSample_ChildChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ChildChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        //registering the event here, 
        //calling "OldClickEventHandler" does not work I get a "NullReferenceException" for "_docEvent"
         HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event _docEvent= (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)(wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.DomDocument;
            _docEvent.onclick += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(OldClickEventHandler);
        }
                    private bool OldClickEventHandler(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
            {
            }
```

At the moment I still do not get the element from the webbrowser which I selected in my WPF-application on the one hand I have a problem with an event for the old webforms webbrowser, where I get a "NullReferenceException"(actually it should not be null from my point of view) and on the other hand for my new(wpf) webbrowser control I can not access "GetElementFromPoint()" because it does not seem to exist for the wpf webbrowser control.

**updated: 17 th june, 10:00 a.m**

It seems, that

```
(HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)(wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.DomDocument;
```

which is inside "wfhSample_ChildChanged" is not ready yet, because when I put the same statement:

```
(HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)(wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.DomDocument;
```

into "NewClickEventHandler(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)" it has the required data in it(,but this is the wrong event handler).

So, now I need to find the correct/proper event handler for my old wpf browser.

**updated: 17 th june, 11:30 a.m**

Ok, now I found a solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368778/getting-html-body-content-in-winforms-webbrowser-after-body-onload-event-execute#18370524) article, I changed my code to:

```
   private void wfhSample_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool complete = false;
        (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).DocumentCompleted += delegate
        {
            if (complete)
                return;
            complete = true;
            // DocumentCompleted is fired before window.onload and body.onload
            (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onload", delegate
            {
                // Defer this to make sure all possible onload event handlers got fired
                System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate
                {
                    // try webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id") here
                    //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("window.onload was fired, can access DOM!");
                    var bla = (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.DomDocument;
                    HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event _docEvent = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)(wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.DomDocument;
                    _docEvent.onclick += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(OldClickEventHandler);
                }, null);
            });
        };

        (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Navigate("http://www.example.com");
    }
    private bool OldClickEventHandler(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point point = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
        System.Drawing.Point refPoint = (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).PointToClient(new System.Drawing.Point(point.X, point.Y));
        System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement refHtmlElement = (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.GetElementFromPoint(refPoint);
        var restult = refHtmlElement.TagName; //this is what I need for the first time,to continue
        return true;
    }
```

And the event handling for the old control works :)

But the "var restult = refHtmlElement.TagName;" returns a "NullReferenceException", there seems to be something wrong with the coordinates.

As soon as I have a solution I will post it or if you have an idea you can help as well:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I found a solution including the winform webbrowser into my wpf application(take a look at my question regarding, processes and resources):

**1.The .xaml part(namespace)([more details](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/)):**

```
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
```

**2.The .xaml part(WebBrowser)([more details](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/)):**

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfhSample" Margin="372,12,12,205" Loaded="wfhSample_Loaded">
    <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        <wf:WebBrowser />
    </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

**3.The code behind file([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368778/getting-html-body-content-in-winforms-webbrowser-after-body-onload-event-execute#18370524)):**

```
   private void wfhSample_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool complete = false;
        (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).DocumentCompleted += delegate
        {
            if (complete)
                return;
            complete = true;
            // DocumentCompleted is fired before window.onload and body.onload
            (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onload", delegate
            {
                // Defer this to make sure all possible onload event handlers got fired
                System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate
                {
                    // try webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id") here
                    //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("window.onload was fired, can access DOM!");
                    var bla = (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.DomDocument;
                    HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event _docEvent = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)(wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.DomDocument;
                    _docEvent.onclick += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(OldClickEventHandler);
                }, null);
            });
        };

        (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Navigate("http://www.example.com");
    }
    private bool OldClickEventHandler(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point point = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
        System.Drawing.Point refPoint = (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).PointToClient(new System.Drawing.Point(point.X, point.Y));
        System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement refHtmlElement = (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.GetElementFromPoint(refPoint);
        var restult = refHtmlElement.TagName; 
        return true;
    }
```

**4.To get the full CSS-Path or XPath you could use Fizzler, HTMLAgilityPack([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736331/get-xpath-from-clicked-htmlelement-in-webbrowsercontrol)).**

Sometimes it is a little buggy(resizing window, changing tabs), the event handler does not fire anymore.